# Setting Location of JButton never works?

Tags: java, location, jbutton

I'm trying to create a button and place it in a certain location, but for some reason it never goes in that specific location. I tried putting it a panel, using setBounds, using setLocation... but It doesn't seem to work...

I'm running this file in another file.

```
public class Inventory extends JPanel
{
   private final static int frameWidth = 200;
   private final static int frameHeight = 500;
   private final static int screenLocationX = 100;
   private final static int screenLocationY = 50;
   private Panel panel;
   private JFrame frame;
   private JPanel jpanel;

public Inventory()
{   
   panel = new Panel();
   frame = new JFrame();

   JButton button = new JButton("Add Gem");
   button.addActionListener(new Listener());
   button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(frameWidth,50));
   // button.setLocation(0,400);
   // button.setBounds(0,400,frameWidth,50);

   panel.setVisible(true);

   frame.setContentPane(panel);
   frame.add(button);

   frame.setVisible(true);
   frame.setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
   frame.setLocation(screenLocationX, screenLocationY);
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.setResizable(false);
}
private class Listener implements ActionListener
{
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {

      panel.addImage(new Gems());

   }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before adding panel to the frame use:
panel.setLayout(null);   //setting the default settings of panel to null
and then use:
button.setBounds(300, 300, 300, 300);   //bounding the button at specific location

this would work..

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn the LayoutManager off

`panel.setLayout(null);`

Answer (score 0):

`JFrame` by default uses a `BorderLayout` and, by default, components are added to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position, unless otherwise specified

In this setup, the  component will be placed on the centre of the frame and sized to fill it

Remember, each platform/OS renders content differently and these differences will change the amount of space required to display your components and all of this will effective the relationships between all the other components...

You consider changing the layout manager and using a combination of `EmptyBorders` and insets/padding to influence the location/size of your components.  Try something like `GridBagLayout` or if your adventurous, checking out `MigLayout`

One of the first lessons you need to learn with GUI program (on just about any platform) is pixel perfect layouts are an illusion, there are too many variables which effect how content is rendered and how these can change the amount of space individual components will need in order to be displayed correctly...